# How to find all documents that belong to the user?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collections of Users and collection of Posts.

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  description: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  user: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
  slug: {type: String, trim: true, lowercase: true},
  createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
})
```

How do I find all documents of PostSchema that belong to a particular user?
Also, is it possible to find all the Posts of the user by user.username field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i would do it, the easy (read: noob) way :p.

**Get posts by given userId:**

```
var PostSchema  =   new Schema({...});

//  allows you to call method findByUser() of the model of posts
//  with parameters: the user_id and the callback function (fn).
PostSchema.statics.findByUser    =   function(userId, fn) {
    this.find({user:userId}, fn);
};

//  we create the posts model.
posts       =   mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema),

//  example usage: find the posts from 'some_user_id' or '2a1a9a...'.
posts.findByUser(some_user_id || '2a1a9a8a3a2a1a9a8a32a1a3', function(err, docs) {
    //  ensure there are no errors and there were docs given.
    if (!err && docs) {
        //  will return the posts.
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```

**Get posts by username (of schema user):**
Same method can be applied, but we first search what the id of the username is in collection users.

```
//  the method we are going to make is dependent on the model/collection 'users',
var users       =   mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

//  we create another static method on the schema of 'posts'.
PostSchema.statics.findByName = function(username, fn) {
    //  we search the user with username 'username'
    //  in model 'users'.
    //  Here, we also are assuming that username = unique.
    this.model('users').findOne({username:username}, function(err, doc) {
        //  ensure there are no errors and there were docs given.
        if (!err && doc) {
            //  we will use the statics we made above.
            //  i have a feeling i lose the context here, so i refer to this.model('posts'),
            //  maybe this.findByUser() als works; i could not test my code.
            this.model('posts').findByUser(doc._id, fn);
        }
        //  if there is a failure, quit and call fn.
        else fn(err, doc);
    });
};
```

These are 'quick' solutions to your questions. I think it could be done much more effective/better.

For you decision to include posts in the user or separately, here's my opinion: It's a coding principle to make your code future-proof.
Think about when the  database gets humongous (=where the name mongo is derived from), where ONE user has over 1,000,000 posts..
So everytime you want to fetch only the userdata, you also get 1,000,000 post documents alltogether. So i think it's better to separate the collections to prevent this.

### old: getter to fetch user document from post.

You can make a method available to all of your docs something like this:

```
PostSchema.methods.getUser = function(callback) {
    // be sure you have the mongoose object.
    mongoose.model('users').findById(this.user, callback);
};
```

So you can just call the method:

```
postDoc.getUser();
```

Wrote this on the top of my head, so it's more pseudo-code. More info here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, will it return all the posts of the user? Or will it just return the user of the particular post doc?

Comment: This is great! What do you think if I change PostSchema to this:
`var PostSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
id: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}, username: String,
}
})`
that would make it easier to search by username. What do you think about this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Given a bit of basic setup:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodetest');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: '', trim: true }
});

var postSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
  description:  { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
  user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  slug: { type: String, trim: true, lowercase: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var User = mongoose.model( 'User', userSchema );

var Post = mongoose.model( 'Post', postSchema );
```

And some data for users:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536c6bf6da1ee15a4c0d7dc6"), "name" : "Neil", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536c6e338534d6a6afd41f64"), "name" : "Bill" }
```

And posts:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536c6bf6da1ee15a4c0d7dc7"),
    "user" : ObjectId("536c6bf6da1ee15a4c0d7dc6"),
    "slug" : "this_post",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-05-09T05:47:34.249Z"),
    "description" : "another post",
    "title" : "this post",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536c6e878534d6a6afd41f65"),
    "user" : ObjectId("536c6e338534d6a6afd41f64"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-05-09T05:58:31.642Z"),
    "slug" : "this_here",
    "description" : "This here",
    "title" : "My Post"
}
```

Finding the user by Id is a simple query:

```
Post.findOne({ user: "536c6bf6da1ee15a4c0d7dc6"  },function(err,doc) {
  console.log( doc );
});
```

Finding the user by the "name", is a bit different

```
Post.find({})
  .populate('user', null, { name: 'Neil' })
  .exec(function(err,posts) {
    posts = posts.filter(function(post) {
      return ( post.user != null );
    });

    console.log( posts );

  });
```

So note the use of `filter` here. The actually querying will actually match everything in `Posts` and the usage of `populate` is just conditionally "filling" the matching gaps. We altered that query just to return the name you want.

But it is the `filter` here that reduces the results. Noting that this is happening "client" side and is not "joining" in any way on the server.

So there is the limitation. If you want to truly restrict, then use embedded documents. If embedding is not possible you will need a another reference somehow in order to search the "User" to find their "Posts", and then retrieve the posts.

It's all a matter of how you approach the problem to best suit you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually can't decide what is better, have embedded posts in the user object or have posts as standalone collection with reference to the user. The post object will also have references to other objects like comments etc... What is general rule of thumb?

Comment: @DenisIvanov Funny enough, your direct use case (which is fairly common) is covered in some detail in documentation on the MongoDB site. The decision to embed or not depends on your actual usage, but you may want to take a look at the [bucketed comments](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/#hybrid-schema-design) part of that document in particular. The general topic talks about posts and comments but the same principles to modeling the relations apply.